# Distance between center of soddy circle and center of incircle

Tags: geometry

> What's the distance between the point $D$ and $H$?
>
> [image]

I tried euler geometry thereom but it doesn't gave me the answer unfortunately

Comment: Expressed in terms of a function of $r_1,r_2,r_3$ (the radii of the 3 "big circles") ?

Comment: What is "Euler Geometry theorem" ? Could you give a reference ?

Comment: Yes i got only the radius of the 3 big blue circles

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry

Comment: Thanks. As the circumscribed circle doesn't play a role, this theorem is hopefuly not the good tool. I think there is a solution using complex geometry with formulas one can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3469224) (see formulas (1) and (2) there).

Comment: I checked out , it is Descartes's theorem , which allow us to find the radius of the little green circle

Comment: Also we can find the radius of the black circle too , my goal is to find the distance between the center of the black circle and the center of the green circle

Comment: This is Problem 727 of Project Euler.

Comment: Yes that is true , i would like to get a formula for this problem , or a starting point to decode it

Comment: I have had a look at this very recently posted project which is larger than the posted question. Nevertheless, it would have been correct to mention it into your question. Besides, you haven't yet included in your question that you are looking for a distance formula **in terms of $r_1,r_2,r_3$** (my remark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a formula, here goes.

For a triangle $\triangle ABC$, let $I$=incenter, $Ge$=Gergonne point, $L$=de Longchamps point, $S$=inner Soddy point (called $D$ in the OP.  It's triangle center $X_{176}$, also called the equal detour point. See Dergiades below.)

Dergiades' paper [*The Soddy Circles*](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2007volume7/FG200726.pdf) gives a formula at the end of section 3.1 for $S$ in terms of the distance between $I$ and $Ge$.

A formula for $GeI$ in terms of $IL$ can be found towards the end of the [Mathworld Gergonne Point entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GergonnePoint.html).

A formula for $LI$ is given in the [Mathworld de Longchamps Point entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/deLongchampsPoint.html).

Beware of typos.

Hope this helps.

Comment: [+1] A good lot of information...